# What is a touch event substitute for onkeypress event?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am using the `onkeypress` event in my text fields to validate numbers only  but it is not working for mobile devices (It is a responsive page, build to be used from desktop and mobile both).

I have found that touch events are used in case of mobile view. Can anybody help with the substitute for `onkeypress` event?

Answer (score 1):

Try This it will work in for Mobile Devices.

```
<html>
<body>
Enter Input:: <input type="text" id="keyup" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("keyup").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the `onkeyup` event?

```js
var inputText = document.getElementById('inputText');

inputText.onkeyup = function() {
 document.getElementById('outputText').innerText = inputText.value;
}
```

```html
<label>Input:</label>
<input type=text id='inputText'/>
<div>Output:<span id='outputText'/></div>
```

Comment: It is not working.. infact no key and mouse events are working